# Android USB reading Arduino return 19600

Tags: android, arduino, usb, ftdi

I am trying to code a Android Activity to perform a read data from Arduino Duemilanove. This Arduino model has a FTDI 232RL chip. I have studied the follow sites and answers:

1. [setting parity with controlTransfer method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546099/setting-parity-with-controltransfer-method)
2. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html
3. http://read.pudn.com/downloads181/sourcecode/embed/842049/usb/serial/ftdi_sio.h__.htm
   and so on...

My code works fine to perform controlTransfer operation on Android USB device. 
But, on bulkTransfer the returned data is just 1 96 0...
I already revised baudrate: Arduino serial runs on 57600 and the controlTransfer to.
Follow a piece of my code:

```
        if(device != null){            
        UsbDeviceConnection conn = usbManager.openDevice(device);
        if (!conn.claimInterface(device.getInterface(0), true)) {
            return;
        }
        //configuring the usb device: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546099/setting-parity-with-controltransfer-method
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0){//reset
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reset Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0x01, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0){//clear Rx
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clean RX Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0x02, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0){//clear Tx
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clean TX Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x02, 0x0000, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0 ){ //flow control none            
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Flow Control fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x0034, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0){//baudrate 57600
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Baudrate fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        if(conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x04, 0x0008, 0, null, 0, 0) < 0){ //data bit 8 parity none stop bit 1
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "settings fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }            

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Reading data...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
        byte[] data = new byte[4096];
        if(conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, data, 4096, 5000) >= 0){
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                builder.append(data[i]);
            }                        
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data: "+builder, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            dispositivos.setText(builder);
        }            

        /*
        try{
            Thread.sleep(5000);                     
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }*/
    }
```

Have anyone some idea or suggestion?

Tanks for help.

Comment: There's working code around the net for talking to the FTDI part from Android with the USB host APIs - finding and examining some of it in comparison would probably help you resolve this problem.  You also need to keep in mind the possibility that you could end up talking to the bootloader rather than your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a lib that helped me to perform a Android communicate with a Arduino Duemilanove. This arduino model has a FTDI chip (232R). This chip is a USB UART interface. 
Then, i am using this lib:

- https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android

It helped me to make a communication between Android and Arduino in a simple way, with few lines of code.

Thanks.